# Check if a string starts with certain character using ngIf and display it

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pipe, angular-ng-if

I am newbies here and I have problem to solve. Please do help, thanks in advance.

I usually display data on screen like this and it works everytime.

```
<h3> Kod Bar : {{ article.barcode_no }} </h3>
```

But now I want to check using *ngIf if *article.barcode_no* starts with certain character, I want it to be remove first before displaying it like this.

```
<h3 *ngIf=" article.article.indexOf(article.barcode_no) === 'S' ? (article.barcode_no).substr(1) : none "> Kod Bar    : {{ article.barcode_no }} </h3>
```

But I keep getting error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

I also tried using Pipe but not working. Please help. Thank you.

```
 <h3 *ngIf=" (article.barcode_no | startsWith : 'S') ? (article.barcode_no).substr(1) : none "> Kod Bar    : {{ article.barcode_no }} </h3>
```

.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'startsWith'
})

export class AccessProviders implements PipeTransform {

  transform(fullText: string, textMatch: string) : boolean {
      return fullText.startsWith(textMatch);
  }
}
```

[ THANK YOU FOR REPLYING YOU GUYS. I APPRECIATE ALL THE ANSWERS! ]

Comment: use `str.chatAt(0) == 'YourChar' ? true : false;`

Comment: try @NajamUsSaqib 's answer  its easy and simple

Comment: I use it like this "<h3> Kod Bar    : {{ article.barcode_no.chatAt(0) == 'S' ? article.barcode_no.substring(1): article.barcode_no }} </h3>"

and got error "ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.barcode_no.chatAt is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<h3 *ngIf="article.barcode_no.indexOf('S',0) == 0 "> Kod Bar    : {{ article.barcode_no.substring(1) }} </h3>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/arun205-string-interpolation?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Your code works, thank you! But now how do I remove the first character from the barcode? 

I wrote like this but does nothing
"<h3 *ngIf="article.barcode_no.indexOf('S',0) == 0 ? article.barcode_no.substr(1) : article.barcode_no "> Kod Bar    : {{ article.barcode_no }} </h3>"

Comment: Updated the answer and stackblitz link. Please try that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you get that error, because at the time of evaluation the article is still not set. To avoid it from template you can use question mark syntax which would check if the property can be safely accessed at the time:

```
 *ngIf=" article?.article.indexOf(article.barcode_no)
```

Also are you sure its 'article.article' ? Because at the pipe you use another value so if it doesnt work then for not the same reason

Answer (score 0):

Try Update your pipe like below

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'startWith'
})
export class StartWithPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(value && typeof(value) === 'string'){
      return value[0] === args;
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: I got error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'startsWith' could not be found"

Comment: there is a type in the code i shared  --  startsWith  -- spelling is different under name : startWith , ---- So just update the name things will work

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this simply by this.

> `{{str.charAt(0) == 'YourChar' ? srt.substring(1): str}};`

Comment: I get "ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.barcode_no.chatAt is not a function" instead.

Comment: my bad it suppose to be `charAt`. i edited the answer..